# In C++, how to I stop my pointers from being 'overridden' when a function is called again?

Tags: c++, pointers, function

all! I don't know if 'overridden' is the right word here. In my
programming class, I have to create a circular list, such that each node
node contains a pointer pointing to the next node and the final node
points to the first node. In addition, there is a tail node that points to
the last node added (its null before any nodes are added).

I cannot populate my list (called a ring) because every time I call the
Ring::Insert(const int& d) function, which inserts a single node, and it
gets to the line "RingNode newNode(d);", the new RingNode object
overwrites the previous RingNode object that was created when I last
called the Ring::Insert(const int& d) function. Obviously, I don't want
this because it messes up my list. How do I make it so every time the
function creates a brand new RingNode object it doesn't interfere with the
previous RingNode objects?

Source code from my header file, just in case:

```
class RingNode {
public:
    RingNode(const int& i=0 ): data(i), next(NULL){}
private:
    int data;  /* ID of player */
    RingNode* next;
friend class Ring;
```

And here is the function in question

```
RingNode* Ring::Insert(const int& d){
    RingNode newNode(d); //This line overwrites previous RingNode objects
    RingNode* refNode = &newNode; //Probably bad form, but that's not my main concern right now
    if (tail==null){
            tail = refNode;
            newNode.next = refNode;
            return refNode;
    }
    newNode.next = (*GetTail()).next;
    (*GetTail()).next = refNode;
    tail = refNode;
    return refNode;
}
```

So, for example, if I execute the following snippet in my main...

```
Ring theRing;
theRing.Insert(5);
theRing.Insert(2);
theRing.Insert(7);
```

If I debug my project I can see that theRing contains only one RingNode,
first it's the 5 RingNode, then the 2 RingNode overwrites it, then the 7
RingNode overwrites that. Thanks for reading and double thanks for your
replies!

EDIT: I replaced

```
RingNode newNode(d); 
RingNode* refNode = &newNode;
```

with

```
RingNode *newNode = new RingNode(d);
```

tweaked the rest of the code, and it's working properly. Thanks so much for the help, guys! Very informative and best of all I now understand *why* it was messing up.

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You're re-using the same local variable on the stack every time.

```
RingNode newNode(d); //This line overwrites previous RingNode objects
```

is a local variable - it lives on the stack.  So it's only valid during the lifetime of your insert method.  However, since you're calling insert several times in a row from the same calling function, your different "newNode"'s wind up at the same place on the stack.

What you probably want to do is

```
RingNode *refNode = new RingNode(d);
```

This will dynamically allocate your RingNode on the heap.

However, now you have to worry about using delete to clean up all the nodes when your Ring is destroyed.

Comment: Actually, I somehow doubt that's what he wants: he probably wants some kind of smart pointer to avoid dealing with the nasties of manual memory management.

Comment: @Matthieu M: Generally I'd agree with you, but in this case it's an assignment for a programming class.  Often in those classes, the point is to teach them to deal with raw pointers properly.  Then they can use the smart pointers in actual tasks once they know how bad raw pointers are.

Comment: Smart pointers have their uses, but in this case, when the pointer use is (apparently) completely encapsulated within an outer Ring class, Smart pointers might just be unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Indeed, this is a textbook example of a case where smart pointers would be a *bad* option.  Smart pointers are useful for large programs where it's hard to test whether resources are being released properly; for small, well-encapsulated, easily-tested classes, they lead to inefficiency at best, and at worst, incorrectness.

Answer (score 1):

```
RingNode newNode(d);
RingNode* refNode = &newNode;
```

Replace with:

```
RingNode* refNode = new RingNode(d);
```

BTW, replace

```
RingNode(const int& i=0 )
```

with:

```
RingNode(int i=0 )
```

There is no need to use reference for small type like integer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create objects that last beyond the scope of your function... so you need to use the `new` operator.

```
RingNode* Ring::Insert(const int& d){
    RingNode* refNode = new RingNode(d); // this line creates a ring node not bound to the scope of the function.
    if (tail==null){
            tail = refNode;
            newNode.next = refNode;
            return refNode;
    }
    newNode.next = (*GetTail()).next;
    (*GetTail()).next = refNode;
    tail = refNode;
    return refNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an object allocated as an "auto" variable, i.e. on the stack, like that. You need to do `RingNode *newNode = new RingNode(d);` and add that.